# Angular Js: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

Whenever I am trying to include $http dependency in my js, I am getting an error related to $injector:modulerr.My code looks like this:

***angularEx.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Fin">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>

   <div ng-controller="PhoneController as phone">
   {{phone.products.subject}}
   </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

***app.js***

```
var app=angular.module('Fin',[]);

app.controller('PhoneController',['$http',function('$http'){

    var store=this;


    $http.get('/dell-streak-7.json').success(function(data){
        store.products=data;
    });
 }]);
```

***dell-streak-7.json file***

```
{
    "subject": "Front Facing 1.3MP Camera", 

}
```

***Output Window:***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared argument in quotes, so it should be:

```
['$http',function($http){}]
```

instead:

```
['$http',function('$http'){
```

Answer (score 3):

Your controller definition is syntactically wrong:

```
app.controller('PhoneController', ['$http', function('$http') {
```

Please note that you have a string literal (`$http`) as function parameter. That's actually the cause of the first error message that says *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected String"*

The following should be correct:

```
app.controller('PhoneController', ['$http', function($http) {
```

The other error (*"$injector:modulerr"*) is probably just a consequential error of the syntax error.